# How should I consume Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries() asynchronously?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm creating a project in VS 2012 using C# and .Net 4.5.  I need to iterate through a directory tree, but I'd like to do it asynchronously.  I think I'll have to do something with the Task class, but I'm not sure.  I also need to be able to report progress on the process.

Comment: Do you want to consume `IEnumerable<string>` (as you stated in the title) that `Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries()` call returns or to asynchronously traverse directory tree using this method?

Comment: I want to traverse the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the entire function in `Task.Run(()=>{ ... });` and it will be run asynchronously in a thread pool thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). It is very useful since it can implement `RunWorkerProgress` and `RunWorkerCompleted` event handlers which you can use to report progress and find out when it has finished the processing. Regarding progress, you won't be able to estimate the part of the work that has been finished using only method `Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries()` (since you don't know how many directories/files there will be), but you will be able to show to the user how many paths have you processed (or similar).